# Split one dataframe into multiple based on index in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a small dataset as follows, say for each city there are two entries:

```
  city  price  quantity
0   bj  10104      5934
1   bj   5423       623
2   sh  15728      9105
3   sh    533        76
4   gz   4012      3558
5   gz    523      7632
6   sz   3770      1946
7   sz   6237      7364
```

I want to split this dataset into two based on the following logic: the first entry of all the cities to be `df1`, which index are `0, 2, 4, 6` and the second entry of all the cities to be `df2`, which index are `1, 3, 5, 7`.

The final results will like this:

**df1:**

```
  city  price  quantity
0   bj  10104      5934
2   sh  15728      9105
4   gz   4012      3558
6   sz   3770      1946
```

**df2:**

```
  city  price  quantity
1   bj   5423       623
3   sh    533        76
5   gz    523      7632
7   sz   6237      7364
```

How could I do that in Pandas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select pair and unpair rows by indexing:

```
df1 = df.iloc[::2]
print (df1)
  city  price  quantity
0   bj  10104      5934
2   sh  15728      9105
4   gz   4012      3558
6   sz   3770      1946

df2 = df.iloc[1::2]
print (df2)
  city  price  quantity
1   bj   5423       623
3   sh    533        76
5   gz    523      7632
7   sz   6237      7364
```

Comment: You can achieve the same using `loc` too